# Python Multiple filetype support with glob.glob

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

I'm trying to use glob.glob to provide support for more than one filetype. The code I have is supposed to take files with the extensions '.pdf', '.xls', and '.xlsx' residing in the directory '/mnt/Test' and execute the code below after files matching have been found.

When I replace the existing for loop with just

```
for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
     print filename
```

It works just fine.

When attempting to run the following code:

```
def main():
    os.chdir("/mnt/Test")
    extensions = ("*.xls", ".xlsx", ".pdf")
    filename = []
    for files in extensions:
        filename.extend(glob.glob(files))
        print filename
        sys.stdout.flush()
        doc_id, version = doc_placeholder(filename)

        print 'doc_id:', doc_id, 'version:', version

        workspace_upload(doc_id, version, filename)

        print "%s has been found. Preparing next phase..." % filename
        ftp_connection.cwd(remote_path)
        fh = open(filename, 'rb')
        ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR %s' % timestr + '_' + filename, fh)
        fh.close()

        send_email(filename)
```

I run across the following error:

```
Report /mnt/Test/fileTest.xlsx has been added.
[]
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 199, in run
self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 368, in dispatch_events
handler.dispatch(event)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/watchdog/events.py", line 330, in dispatch
_method_map[event_type](event)
File "observe.py", line 14, in on_created
fero.main()
File "/home/tesuser/project-a/testing.py", line 129, in main
doc_id, version = doc_placeholder(filename)
File "/home/testuser/project-a/testing.py", line 58, in doc_placeholder
payload = {'documents':[{'document':{'name':os.path.splitext(filename)[0],'parentId':parent_id()}}]}
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 105, in splitext
return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, altsep, extsep)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 91, in _splitext
sepIndex = p.rfind(sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

How can I edit the code above to achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance, everyone. Appreciate the help.

Comment: what is the doc_placeholder function?

Comment: `doc_placeholder` includes this snippet, `os.path.splitext(filename)`.  Assuming `filename` is the list you passed in you've given a list to `os.path.splittext` when it's expecting a string.

Comment: Dodell, the doc_placeholder function is a function I created that creates a document placeholder using restful api on a test environment. This portion works without any issues when I use the `for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):` loop.

Comment: Steven, ah I see. The snippet you're referring to is `os.path.splitext(filename)[0],`. What would be the best approach to this considering what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`doc_placeholder` includes this snippet, `os.path.splitext(filename)`.  Assuming `filename` is the list you passed in you've given a list to `os.path.splittext` when it is expecting a string.

Fix this by iterating over each filename instead of trying to process the entire list at once.

```
def main():
    os.chdir("/mnt/Test")
    extensions = ("*.xls", "*.xlsx", "*.pdf")
    filenames = []  # made 'filename' plural to indicate it's a list

    # building list of filenames moved to separate loop
    for files in extensions: 
        filenames.extend(glob.glob(files)) 

    # iterate over filenames    
    for filename in filenames: 
        print filename
        sys.stdout.flush()
        doc_id, version = doc_placeholder(filename)

        print 'doc_id:', doc_id, 'version:', version

        workspace_upload(doc_id, version, filename)

        print "%s has been found. Preparing next phase..." % filename
        ftp_connection.cwd(remote_path)
        fh = open(filename, 'rb')
        ftp_connection.storbinary('STOR %s' % timestr + '_' + filename, fh)
        fh.close()

        send_email(filename)
```

Comment: Testing this now, Steven. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the asterisk in front of `".xlsx"` and `".pdf"`

Comment: You, sir, are outstanding. Thanks so much for this! Exactly what I needed.